# Is there a C#/.NET standard implementation of CRC?

Tags: c#, crc

I know that implementations exist for [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) and [SHA-256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) in System.Security.Cryptography.

Is there anything built in that can compute CRC hashes?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff385753(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: I'm aware of that post. I googled it FIRST, not like a jackwad who posts things without first looking. That wasn't my question. Is there certainly not a built-in facility or is it possible that he is a human being and missed something (like we all do sometimes).

Comment: Seriously, who is downvoting my question? This is crap. It's a totally valid question.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee431960.aspx

Comment: You can avoid the downvotes by showing your prior research, and save us some time by not having us repeat the same research.

Comment: I saw that but it is in a strange assembly... SPOT.Hardware

Comment: Does it not stand to reason that on a board like this people aren't stupid enough to post things without first doing something as simple as a Google search? I mean really...

Comment: Google-fu on MSDN is pretty good.  If you Google CRC32, and it doesn't show up in the first page of Google Search Results on MSDN, then there's probably not a built-in function to do it.

Comment: The first thing we're going to do for a question like this is to Google it, and find the plethora of external solutions that already exist.  So no, we don't just make the assumption that you've already done this.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is one built into the .NET Framework. Use an open source version such as [Damien Guard's library](https://github.com/damieng/DamienGKit/blob/master/CSharp/DamienG.Library/Security/Cryptography/Crc32.cs).

Comment: I really need a CRC16 library. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Since .NET 6, there is a `System.IO.Hashing` namespace which provides a `Crc32` and a `Crc64` implementation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.hashing?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-6.0

Comment: Actually, it's not integrated in .NET 6
It's just in a separate Nuget (https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Hashing/) available for .NET 6.0+, .NET Core 2.0+, .NET Framework 4.6.1+